# Trying to build multiple accordions with bootstrap collapse. Clicking on a second accordion collapses the first

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on building an accordion data type in AngularJS. I have this code that works as far as basic functionality, but I have a big issue.

This is the code:

```js
var app = angular.module('accordions', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fieldAccordions = [{
    fieldAccordionHeader: 'Header 1',
    fieldAccordionItems: [{
      desc: 'Item 1 - A'
    }, {
      desc: 'Item 1 - B'
    }]
  }, {
    fieldAccordionHeader: 'Header 2',
    fieldAccordionItems: [{
      desc: 'Item 2'
    }]
  }, {
    fieldAccordionHeader: 'Header 3',
    fieldAccordionItems: [{
      desc: 'Item 3'
    }]
  }];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="accordions">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Accordions</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="field in fieldAccordions track by $index">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{ $index }}">
            {{ field.fieldAccordionHeader }} </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse{{ $index }}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div ng-repeat="item in field.fieldAccordionItems track by $index">{{ item.desc }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

On the page that I am working on I need an accordion, followed by other fields such as text, images, and then another accordion. This code will work for a first accordion. When I call fieldAccordions again on the page, opening its headers will open the headers from the initial fieldAccordions element.

This is how my interface looks:

```
First fieldAccordions on the page: (I'll just call it fieldAccordions1)
Header 1 for fieldAccordions1 // opens Header 1 for fieldAccordions1
Header 2 for fieldAccordions1 // opens Header 2 for fieldAccordions1
Header 3 for fieldAccordions1 // opens Header 3 for fieldAccordions1


//Text

//Images

Second fieldAccordions on the page: (I'll just call it fieldAccordions2)
Header 1 for fieldAccordions2  // opens Header 1 for fieldAccordions1
Header 2 for fieldAccordions2  // opens Header 2 for fieldAccordions1
Header 3 for fieldAccordions2  // opens Header 3 for fieldAccordions1
Header 4 for fieldAccordions2  // opens Header 4 for fieldAccordions2
// header 4 opens for fieldAccordions2 since fieldAccordions1 does not have a 4th child
```

Can anyone help me with this? I think the problem is the way I am using $index. I need to have a unique id every time I generate a new fieldAccordion, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('accordions', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fieldAccordions = [{
    fieldAccordionHeader: 'Header 1',
    collapseToggle: 'one',
    fieldAccordionItems: [{
      desc: 'Item 1 - A'
    }, {
      desc: 'Item 1 - B'
    }]
  }, {
    fieldAccordionHeader: 'Header 2',
    collapseToggle: 'two',
    fieldAccordionItems: [{
      desc: 'Item 2'
    }]
  }, {
    fieldAccordionHeader: 'Header 3',
    collapseToggle: 'three',
    fieldAccordionItems: [{
      desc: 'Item 3'
    }]
  }];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="accordions">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Accordions</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="field in fieldAccordions track by $index">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{field.collapseToggle}}">
            {{ field.fieldAccordionHeader }} </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="{{field.collapseToggle}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div ng-repeat="item in field.fieldAccordionItems track by $index">{{ item.desc }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Try with I believe, there was some issues with names of collapse, reference etc. To be sure It's best to have it clearly named and separated.